# Can't generate CMake files with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, glfw

I'm trying to use CMake with Visual Studio for a 3D class, but whenever I open the provided CMake project, Visual Studio can't generate CMake files. I get the following error (some parts of the output were in French so I translated them):

```
CMake generation started with the default configuration: 'x64-Debug (par défaut)'.
1> Command line: "cmd.exe" /c ""c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="D:\Scolaire\11 - 2A\INF443\1 - Tutoriels\create_window_commented\out\install\x64-Debug (par défaut)" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\Ninja\ninja.exe" "D:\Scolaire\11 - 2A\INF443\1 - Tutoriels\create_window_commented" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: D:\Scolaire\11 - 2A\INF443\1 - Tutoriels\create_window_commented\out\build\x64-Debug (par défaut)
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.26.28805.0
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.26.28805.0
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe - broken
1> [CMake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
1> [CMake]   The C compiler
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   is not able to compile a simple test program.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   It fails with the following output:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     Change Dir: D:/Scolaire/11 - 2A/INF443/1 - Tutoriels/create_window_commented/out/build/x64-Debug (par défaut)/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]     Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_cbae0 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_cbae0.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
1> [CMake]     [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_cbae0.exe
1> [CMake]     FAILED: cmTC_cbae0.exe 
1> [CMake]     cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_cbae0.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_cbae0.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_cbae0.exe /implib:cmTC_cbae0.lib /pdb:cmTC_cbae0.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
1> [CMake]     RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_cbae0.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_cbae0.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
1> [CMake]     The specified file could not be found
1> [CMake]     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
1> [CMake] See also "D:/Scolaire/11 - 2A/INF443/1 - Tutoriels/create_window_commented/out/build/x64-Debug (par défaut)/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
1> [CMake] See also "D:/Scolaire/11 - 2A/INF443/1 - Tutoriels/create_window_commented/out/build/x64-Debug (par défaut)/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
1> Execution failed 'cmd.exe' '/c ""c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="D:\Scolaire\11 - 2A\INF443\1 - Tutoriels\create_window_commented\out\install\x64-Debug (par défaut)" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\Ninja\ninja.exe" "D:\Scolaire\11 - 2A\INF443\1 - Tutoriels\create_window_commented" 2>&1"'. Error: ''cmd.exe' '/c ""c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="D:\Scolaire\11 - 2A\INF443\1 - Tutoriels\create_window_commented\out\install\x64-Debug (par défaut)" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\Ninja\ninja.exe" "D:\Scolaire\11 - 2A\INF443\1 - Tutoriels\create_window_commented" 2>&1"' was returned with end code: 1'.
```

Other people in my class are using the same provided files and don't have errors so the problem can't be from this. I use Windows 10 and the latest version of Visual Studio (I tried to uninstall and reinstall it). The C++ and CMake tools are installed within Visual Studio.

The provided project should only open an empty windows, it looks like this:

```
PS D:\Scolaire\11 - 2A\INF443\1 - Tutoriels\create_window_commented> ls


    Répertoire : D:\Scolaire\11 - 2A\INF443\1 - Tutoriels\create_window_commented


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       25/05/2020     14:09                .vs
d-----       25/05/2020     14:09                out
d-----       03/08/2018     15:10                src
-a----       11/03/2020     08:59            175 CMakeLists.txt
-a----       02/03/2020     17:37            214 Makefile
-a----       02/03/2020     17:37            229 meson.build
-a----       11/03/2020     08:59            847 README
```

Do you know what the cause could be ? Thanks!

Comment: First thing, try to use path without spaces.

Comment: I tried in the default Visual Studio folder, `C:\Users\Myvh773\source\repos\create_window_commented`, and it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the `CMakeLists.txt`, the parameters inside this file were for Unix instead of Windows.

Edit: the `CMakeLists.txt` that didn't work was this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(pgm)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra")

add_executable(pgm src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(pgm glfw)
```

I made the following changes.

From `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra")` to:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
    set(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib_windows/glfw3_win/include")
    include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    set(GLFW_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib_windows/glfw3_win/lib/glfw3.lib") # Set directory to precompiled version of glfw3
```

From `target_link_libraries(pgm glfw)` to:

```
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${source_files}) # Allow to explore source directories as a tree
    target_link_libraries(pgm ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
```

I didn't write this code, I just understood that the wrong lines of code were meant for Unix so I replaced them with the right lines of code from another `CMakeLists.txt` from a similar provided OpenGL project.

Comment: This response is pretty vague... can you please show an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

My solution — add this right before 'project' in top cmake file:

```
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")
```